# flexbox row with much text has weird positioning

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a 4 div grid like this

```
<div class="flex-row">
    <div id="img1">...</div>
    <div id="img3">...</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row">
    <div>...</div>
    <div id="textdiv">...</div>
</div>
```

`.flex-row` divs are flexbox rows. My problem is that `#textdiv` is totally misaligned when there is lenghty text in there.

Is anyone able to tell me whats the matter with the `#textdiv`? Why doesn't it settle itself in the flex correctly?

I've created a pen showing the bug http://codepen.io/deiga/pen/Axkwg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to set [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) to `flex-start` ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/puEhg)):

```css
#grid > .flex-row {
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: flex-start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  font-size: 1.25em; /* 20/16 px */
  line-height: 1.7;
  -webkit-align-items:flex-start; /* <!-- Add this for older webkit support */
  align-items:flex-start; /* <-- Add this */
}
```

By default, `align-items` is set to `baseline`, hence why the bottom of the first line of your paragraph is lined up with the bottom of the image in the first column.